# Spring Data CrudRepository as method Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Is there a way to create Spring Repository as Bean in configuration class? So that I can have multiple repositories in one class instead of creating new interface file for each entity?

I tried to create a nested @Repository interface but that couldn't been autowired.

Edit:
tried (as said earlier)

```
@Repository
public static interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastNameStartsWithIgnoreCase(String lastName);
}
```

which is inner class in SpringBootApplication class. I cannot use @Bean annotation beacuse it gives compilation errors

Comment: Please show the code of what you have tried.

Comment: Ofcourse yu cannot use `@Bean` method. The interfaces are detected and Spring Data creates the implementation. You will have to have a interface for the entities you need. Be it in a single file as inner interface or top level they have to be there.

Comment: Well but this is exactly the problem - it doesn't work for with inner class interfaces

Comment: why would you define an interface repository as an inner class?

Comment: Well. As you can see in post I don't want to have 10 empty interfaces. I would rather have one class in which I can declare those interfaces.

Comment: At runtime that doesn't matter. You still have 10 interfaces but they are 1 level deeper as normal . Also what doesn't work. Done several demo's like that and worked like a charm.

Comment: I know that it doesn't matter. It is simply to make project tidier. Demo's? All I need to know is how to declare multiple Repositories in one class

Comment: As stated done it many times like that... So please specify WHAT doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and doesn't specify WHAT isn't working... Doesn't it compile, doesn't it inject... Also adding `@Repository` isn't doing anything. Post your application class don't post small snippets.

Comment: What doesn't work is the code which is in question, obviously. When it is in class and I'm trying to autowire it somewhere I'm getting "No qualifying bean of type". When it is a separate file it works, when inner interface in Configuration class it doesn't. Question is how to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a method considerNestedRepositories.